# how to recover funds from blockchain

Tags: blockchain.info, wallet-recovery

I forgot my password of Blockchain Wallet and i tried to recover from (12 word backup phrase key but it has generated a new wallet) on the same 12 word backup key and it has different (wallet ID) but my funds couldn't recovered, so i need guidance to recover my funds from Old wallet into new Wallet any idea what should i do?

Answer (score 1):

1. Use https://login.blockchain.com/#/recover and note that it says

   > Recovering your funds will create a new wallet ID.

OR

2. Read https://support.blockchain.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001298143-Your-Secret-Private-Key-Recovery-Phrase-The-Failsafe where it says

   > The recovery phrase generated in your Blockchain wallet is compatible with other bitcoin wallets that implement BIP44/BIP39.

   So you can go to https://bitcoin.org/en/choose-your-wallet and select any other wallet that supports BIP44/BIP39. Then use that wallet to recover control over your money by selecting wallet recovery at startup and entering your recovery phrase.

Comment: Hi thank you for answering but the problem is i tried to recover my funds from my wallet and i used 12 word recovery phrase but it has generated a new wallet on the same email with a different wallet ID and it has no fund on it now what should i do ?

Comment: @Zubair try option 2 ?