# 2009-2011 digital wallets

Tags: wallet-recovery, wallet.dat

Is there away to find digital wallets online from 2009-2011. With the wallet ID - 12 words - 64 private n public - bit address - hash - signature. - my friend who died left me to remember before he died?

Also how do I find old e-mail addresses I had in 2009-2011 because he also sent me all the info and scan to the email?

Comment: What wallets were available in 2009-2011

Answer (score 0):

> **Is there away to find digital wallets online from 2009-2011.**

In general no.

You have to have some idea of the particular wallet software that was downloaded onto a PC or phone and access to the device or to backups of the device or backups of it's recovery-phrase or private-keys. Alternatively you need to know a company name and account details for an online account if a custodial account was used instead of a self-managed wallet.

See [I have lost my wallet, what can I do?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/103688/13866)

> **With the wallet ID - 12 words**

I think only Blockchain.com use the term "Wallet-ID".

See [how to recover funds from blockchain](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/105980/13866)

Comment: Thank you, what were the digital wallets between 2009-2011. I have every character for everything. Privat, public, bit address, wallet Id, 12 word phrase . 



Know how to find old email accounts? I Need to get into old email account he sent me.